# Docker Swarm over IPSec VTI (Unifi site-to-site)

Tags: vpn, docker-swarm, docker-networking, unifi

I have setup a Docker Swarm using 3 servers;

```
Master node
Home - local IP 192.168.178.250

Worker node 1
Remote - local IP 10.10.10.200

Worker node 2
Remote - local IP 10.10.10.250
```

Both sites have a Unifi gateway (USG Pro/USG) and I've setup a site-to-site connection between them (auto settings, IPSec VTI)

I was able to add the 2 nodes using join tokens from the master since both worker nodes can access `192.168.178.250` via the VPN tunnel, and I've been successful in setting up multiple containers. However, it seems that the connection keeps timing out within the ingress(?) network.

---

Here's a chart explaining my setup
[image: setup]

For example, I have a UptimeRobot rule that checks the "NGINX (hello world)" availability.
The NGINX container is available through the "traefik_default" network and via Traefik linked to a domain.

```
CURL attempt 1: https://nginx.domain.tld/ - 200 ok
CURL attempt 2: https://nginx.domain.tld/ - 200 ok
CURL attempt 3: https://nginx.domain.tld/ - 504 Gateway timeout
CURL attempt 4: https://nginx.domain.tld/ - 504 Gateway timeout
CURL attempt 5: https://nginx.domain.tld/ - 504 Gateway timeout
```

While curl on the public domain gives a `504 Gateway Timeout` the direct IP (over the VPN) seems to be reachable `http://10.10.10.200 - 200 Ok`

At first I figured it might be Traefik, but when I explore the portainer interface than 2/3 times it can't load services or containers where the log is saying something like: `Unable to connect to portainer agent on 10.10.10.200/250`

I'm having a really hard time to figure out where it is going wrong, is there a different VPN type required to get a more stable setup, or is this even a viable solution at all?